# Vue Js render dynamic information in template

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to populate user ID in popup when user click on link and i get information form data attribute and pass it to object to show different id every time user click on link. BUT i am getting the same if which i clicked first time.

Below code is JQuery and Vue mix.

**JS Code**

```
$('.lead-details-btn').on('click', function(){

new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data() {
        return {
            message: $(this).data('id')
        }
    }
});

});
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```js
vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      message: ''
    }
  }
});

$('.lead-details-btn').on('click', function() {
  console.log( $(this).attr('id'))
  vm.message = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.5/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
  <button id="btn-1" class="lead-details-btn">btn-1</button>
  <button id="btn-2" class="lead-details-btn">btn-2</button>
  <button id="btn-3" class="lead-details-btn">btn-3</button>
</div>
```